# Intellij idea - Spring Bean Configuration File

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Introduction:
I have problem coz I'm green in Intellij Idea. I started my jurney in spring framework but I found big stone for ant on my way also I have map only for eclipse tourists.

Main problem:
I like to create xml file (Spring Bean Configuration File). But i dont know how. I was trying install plugins like(From Intellij Idea repository):
Unitils plugin,
XML Bean Generator,
IdeaSpring.
But only what I get its errors.

I saw guy which did it in eclipse and this was looking so amazing:
http://screenshooter.net/101973359/ycqhwbh
Now I dont know is realy Intellij Idea inteligent tool if dumb cant understead.

Can u guys also (if possible) give me some nice tips for future to be best programmer in the universe? Or my eye missed some nice treads?

Comment: IntelliJ has a built in plugin for Spring. Go to File > new Project and create your spring project. This should solve your issue. If Spring wont show up. Install Spring plugin. Note: If using spring 4.x there is no necessary of web.xml files or bean config files. Everything can be automated in Class files. There are plenty of examples in internet on how to do those.

Answer (score 8):

Enable Spring plugin in your project:

```
File-> Settings ->Plugins
```

And check Spring plugins (`Spring Support`, `Spring MVC,` etc).

Then select directory you want to put your Spring configuration in, right click and select

```
 New -> XML Configuration File -> Spring Config
```

Alternatively you can just do `File-> New File` and just create xml file and enter namespace definitions. IDEA should recognize your project as Spring project and configure plugins itself...

Or, as  Anvesh Vejandla  mentioned, you can just create a new Spring project

Answer (score 0):

File->New->Project...
Choose Spring, check "Create empty spring-config.xml"
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add dependencies{spring core , spring context}  at pox.xml from this web site https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/5.3.1

Then select directory you want to put your Spring configuration in, right click and select

New -> XML Configuration File -> Spring Config