# Creating a Spring Bean for Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I'm having some issues with using the Spring framework in Intellij. My question will be in reference to this post:

[Intellij idea - Spring Bean Configuration File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218307/intellij-idea-spring-bean-configuration-file)

- *"Enable Spring plugin in your project and check Spring plugins (Spring Support, Spring MVC, etc)":* **There is no option to do this
  when I view the available plugins in my Intellij**
- *"IntelliJ has a built in plugin for Spring. Go to File > new Project and create your spring project":* **There is also no available option
  for me to create a new Spring project**

My primary goal is to create a bean but obviously that isn't an option without the Spring framework working. Can someone walk me through how to get it set up?

Comment: Are you using the Community Edition?

Comment: Yes I am using Community Edition, problem solved.

Comment: It doesn't have the Spring goodies built-in. See bottom of page here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/